# Length of truncated Farey sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Farey sequence $F_n$ of order $n$ is defined as a sequence of completely reduced fractions $a/b$ such that $0 \le a \le b \le n$.

$$ F_1 = \frac{0}{1}, \  \frac{1}{1}$$
$$ F_2 = \frac{0}{1}, \  \frac{1}{2}, \  \frac{1}{1}$$
$$ F_3 = \frac{0}{1}, \  \frac{1}{3}, \  \frac{1}{2}, \  \frac{2}{3}, \  \frac{1}{1}$$
$$ F_4 = \frac{0}{1}, \  \frac{1}{4}, \  \frac{1}{3}, \  \frac{1}{2}, \  \frac{2}{3}, \  \frac{3}{4}, \  \frac{1}{1}$$
$$ F_5 =\frac{0}{1}, \  \frac{1}{5}, \  \frac{1}{4}, \  \frac{1}{3}, \  \frac{2}{5}, \  \frac{1}{2}, \  \frac{3}{5}, \  \frac{2}{3}, \  \frac{3}{4}, \  \frac{4}{5}, \  \frac{1}{1}$$
$$ F_6 = \frac{0}{1}, \  \frac{1}{6}, \  \frac{1}{5}, \  \frac{1}{4}, \  \frac{1}{3}, \  \frac{2}{5}, \  \frac{1}{2}, \  \frac{3}{5}, \  \frac{2}{3}, \  \frac{3}{4}, \  \frac{4}{5}, \  \frac{5}{6}, \  \frac{1}{1}$$
$$ F_7 = \frac{0}{1}, \  \frac{1}{7}, \  \frac{1}{6}, \  \frac{1}{5}, \  \frac{1}{4}, \  \frac{2}{7}, \  \frac{1}{3}, \  \frac{2}{5}, \  \frac{3}{7}, \  \frac{1}{2}, \  \frac{4}{7}, \  \frac{3}{5}, \  \frac{2}{3}, \  \frac{5}{7}, \  \frac{3}{4}, \  \frac{4}{5}, \  \frac{5}{6}, \  \frac{6}{7}, \  \frac{1}{1}$$

It is known that $|F_{n}|=1+\sum _{m=1}^{n}\varphi (m)$,
where using $\varphi(m)$ is the Euler's totient function.

The corresponding sequence of cardinalities, https://oeis.org/A049643, starts with
$$2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 19, 23, 29, 33, 43, 47,...$$

I'm wondering if there are some works that consider truncated Farey sequences
$F_{n,k}$, that is sequences of completely reduced fractions $a/b$ such that $0 \le a \le k \le b \le n$.
For example
$$ F_{7,3} = \frac{0}{1}, \
 \frac{1}{7}, \  \frac{1}{6}, \  \frac{1}{5}, \  \frac{1}{4}, \  \frac{2}{7}, \  \frac{1}{3}, \  \frac{2}{5}, \  \frac{3}{7}, \  \frac{1}{2}, \  \frac{3}{
5}, \  \frac{2}{3}, \  \frac{3}{4},
\  \frac{1}{1}
$$

Is something known about the cardinalities $|F_{n,k}|$ ?
The first values are

$$|F_{n,0}|= 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,...$$
$$|F_{n,1}|= 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 ,...$$
$$|F_{n,2}|= 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 29, 30 ,...$$
$$|F_{n,3}|= 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 14, 16, 18, 20, 23, 24, 27, 29, 31, 33, 36, 37, 40, 42 ,...$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$|F_{n,k}|=\sum_{b=k}^n \sum_{a=1}^k [(a,b) = 1] = \sum_{b=k}^n \sum_{a=1}^k \sum_{d\mid a\\ d\mid b} \mu(d) = \sum_{k\leq db\leq n} \lfloor \frac k d\rfloor \mu(d) = \sum_{d=1}^k \sum_{b=\lceil \frac k d \rceil}^{\lfloor \frac nd\rfloor} \lfloor \frac k d\rfloor \mu(d) = \sum_{d=1}^k (\lfloor \frac nd\rfloor - \lceil \frac k d \rceil+ 1) \lfloor \frac k d\rfloor \mu(d) = C + \sum_{d=1}^k \lfloor \frac nd\rfloor \lfloor \frac k d\rfloor \mu(d) = C + O(k\log k) + n \sum_{d=1}^k \lfloor \frac k d\rfloor \frac{\mu(d)}d$$
So it's a linear function of $n$ up to an error of at most $k\log k$. It could be exactly calculated using $n\mod \text{lcm}(1,2,...,k)$, because then we don't need to use $\lfloor \frac n d\rfloor = \frac nd + O(1)$ but can instead use the exact $\lfloor \frac n d\rfloor = \frac nd - \frac{n\mod d}d$ . Alternatively, just $\sum_{d=1}^k (\lfloor \frac nd\rfloor - \lceil \frac k d \rceil+ 1) \lfloor \frac k d\rfloor \mu(d)$ lets one compute it efficiently.

For the slope, it might be worth noting that it's also $\sum_{d=1}^k \frac{\varphi(d)}d = \frac6{\pi^2}k + O(\log^2(k))$